# Which model should I choose for my ARIMA time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection

I'm working on a monthly seasonal time series and I'm trying to figure out my SARIMA model by identifying a possible model.
These are my output (ACF and PACF) after first difference
What are my possible models (p?, q?, P?,D?, Q?)
PS : for my case d=1
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first plot does not have an $x$ axis annotation.

The second plot has a noticeable spike at lag 1, so I'd recommend looking at a seasonal model, $D=1$. Run that and look at ACF/PACF plots for residuals again. [The bottom of this page](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/5) gives some indications on what AR and MA orders are indicated by certain patterns in these  models. Refit models iteratively until the residuals look like white noise, based on ACF/PACF plots, but also based on time series plots or [seasonal plots](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/1) of the residuals.

Alternatively, fit various models and compare them using information criteria. [This is really the modern approach](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/6) - the Box-Jenkins approach is more of historical interest.